# I only Have Cold water from kitchen faucet. No hot water

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I just moved into a house that I normally have rented out. No hot water comes out of the kitchen faucet. When I turn it to either Hot setting or cold setting, regardless the water comes out cold. There is plenty of water, it is all cold. The hot water works in the rest of the house so that is not a problem. I have hot water heater turned all the way up. I tried turning off/on valves under the sink and this did nothing. A few years ago a friend of mine hooked up a garbage disposal under the sink and perhaps that created the problem? Not sure as tenant never complained about the only cold water

Comment: Welcome to DIY! Are you giving the hot water enough time to come out? It can take some time depenidng on where it's coming from. Is it a single or double handle faucet? The garbage disposal shouldn't be a reason for the water not working properly.

Comment: Have you done any investigation to find out where the hot water supply discontinues being hot? It's hard to say much from here with what we know.

Comment: You could do a test to see if it is the faucet. Buy a 10 dollar faucet supply hose/line that fits the valve you have, disconnect the supply line that goes from the hot valve to the faucet then attach the new line you bought, put the unattached end in a large bucket and turn the valve back on and let it run to see if it get hot.( it may take a while )  **If it does get hot you now know that it is your faucet that is the problem**, if does not get hot then you know that the problem is further upstream.